# python compilation does not find ssl

Tags: python, cmake, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have compiled and run without an issue python3 on a rpi 3. Now It fails after the compilation to use pip on an rpi 4

These are the steps of the compilation

```
version=3.9.5

mkdir ~/temp
wget -O ~/temp/Python-$version.tar.xz https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$version/Python-$version.tar.xz

cd ~/temp

tar xf Python-$version.tar.xz

cd Python-$version

./configure --enable-optimizations --with-openssl=/usr/lib/ssl
make -j -l 4

sudo make altinstall
```

and whereis ssl.h shows

```
ssl: /usr/lib/ssl /etc/ssl /usr/share/man/man7/ssl.7ssl.gz
```

but still configure complains

```
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/lib/ssl... no
checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... no
checking for --with-ssl-default-suites... python
checking for --with-builtin-hashlib-hashes... md5,sha1,sha256,sha512,sha3,blake2
```

I can confirm later pip complains about ssl.

Any idea why python compilation should not include properly ssl ?

Comment: "whereis ssl.h shows ..." - It shows that actually you don't have the header `ssl.h`: `/usr/lib/ssl` contains **library** files, `/etc/ssl` is a configuration for SSL and `/usr/share/man/man7/ssl.7ssl.gz` is a man page for SSL. Probably, you forgot to install development SSL package.

Comment: Do you have `libssl-dev` installed (assuming you use `Raspbian`)?

Comment: @HTF libssl-dev is installed and yes it's raspian.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you are right there is no ssl.h

Answer (score 0):

if some one comes across this

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared
make -j -l 4
sudo make altinstall
sudo ldconfig
```

did work for me. However still not sure if that is a valid solution